# Write a nested filter in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

Assume this

```js
const someList = Immutable.fromJS([
  {'id': 2, foo: 'puppet'}, 
  {'id': 4, foo: 'kitten'}
]);

//Then I filter like so

const entry = someList.filter(elem => {
    return elem.get('id') === 4
});

console.log(entry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

This gives me

```
{'id': 4, foo: 'kitten'}
```

How to write the filter function, that `entry` equals to `kitten`, without an additional line.

I tried

```
const entry = someList.filter(elem => {
    return elem.get('id') === 4
}).get('foo');
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the item with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

With `find`, you get the first found element on which the predicate returns `true`.

```
const entry = someList.find(elem => elem.get('id') === 4).get('foo');
```

if you are not sure about finding an element, you need a default object as well.

```
const entry = (someList.find(elem => elem.get('id') === 4) || {}).get('foo');
```

Comment: `find` instead of `filter`. the result is an item, not an array. do you want to get an array as result?

Comment: I just saw that you used `find` instead of filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use destructuring, and `find` not `filter`:

```js
const someList = [{'id':2,foo:'puppet'},{'id':4,foo:'kitten'}];
const { foo: entry } = someList.find(({ id }) => id == 4);
console.log(entry);
```

ImmutableJS version:

```js
const someList = Immutable.fromJS([
    {'id': 2, foo: 'puppet'}, 
    {'id': 4, foo: 'kitten'}
]);

const entry = someList.find(elem => elem.get('id') === 4).get("foo");

console.log(entry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array after filter:

```js
    
const someList = Immutable.fromJS([
  {'id': 2, foo: 'puppet'}, 
  {'id': 4, foo: 'kitten'}
]);

const entry = someList.filter(elem => {
  return elem.get('id') === 4
}).map(el => el.get('foo'));

console.log(entry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```